# RecyclerView not displaying my data

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm very new to Android and I started practicing with `RecyclerView` and for some reason my data does not show. If you could help that would be great! Ty.
Here's some code.

**Main Activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
    adapter = new myAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
}

public static List<Information> getData() {
    List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] titles = { "TEST_TEXT1",
                        "TEST_TEXT1",
                        "TEST_TEXT1" };
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) 
        Information current = new Information();
        current.title = titles[i];
        data.add(current);
    }

    return data;
}
```

**myAdapter:**

```
public class myAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();

    public myAdapter(Context ctx, List<Information> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, viewGroup, false);
        myViewHolder holder = new myViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Information current = data.get(i);
        viewHolder.user.setText(current.title);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView user;
        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            user = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowUser);
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom Row XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="TEST_TEXT"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity layout XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't assign your List to anything. Change your constructor to assign your member variables as shown below.

```
public myAdapter(Context ctx, List<Information> data) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.data = data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem

```
 public myAdapter(Context ctx, List<Information> data) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
}
```

you forgot `data`.